# bluemix node-red debug not working

Tags: debugging, ibm-cloud, node-red

I'm working with a node-red application inside Bluemix. It worked well but now the debug sidebar did not show no message. 
The application log traces correctly the messages incoming from the IoT device. 
I tried to deploy again, to change browser, nothing changed: the debug sidebar is always empty.
What to do to have again messages showed?

Thanks

Comment: Just to check a couple of things, debug nodes can be disabled/enabled by clicking on tab on the end of the node. Also if you double click on the node you can enable output to the logs as well, do you see the debug output in the logs? Please edit your question with more details about your flow.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm quite expert with debug nodes and I have it all enabled. I was working on it yesterday and everything was good, then I left and today, when I opened again, the debug was empty. Don't know what's wrong but I just tried to create a new node-red app from scratch and it has the same behaviour: empty debug. The new app has simply an input iot node from wuickstart and a debug output.

Comment: You will probably do better bringing this up on the mailing list where some proper debugging can be done as Stackoverflow is not suited to back and forth. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/node-red

Comment: I'm trying to understand if the app is working properly and I changed the debug nodes to debug also to the console. Than the debug to the console works and the messages are showed correctly, still nothing on the debug sidebar

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I've also encountered this issue last year. Relaunching node-red resolved the issue but this time, I'm running node-red on a container and many others are using it so I can't just re-deploy it this time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Simple Timestamp injection plugged to a debug output and for some reason nothing was shown on the debug side panel.
The solution in my case was simply to set no proxy for the application address in the web browser. After that debugging came through

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was a different version of NodeRed was installed on the server, all I had to do is clear Chrome cache.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I simply didn't have the debug tab selected.  I thought I did.  You have to click on the little bug icon.  I was getting the messages all along, just didn't have the correct display.